# VHDL - looping through an array

Tags: vhdl

I wanted to loop through an array elements and later output them.

I don't think that the for loop is correct.

Could someone help with this, please ?

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gJzJQ.png)

Comment: See [ask] **DO NOT post images of code, data, error messages, etc.** - copy or type the text into the question. Please reserve the use of images for diagrams or demonstrating rendering bugs, things that are impossible to describe accurately via text. For more information please see the Meta FAQ entry [Why not upload images of code/errors when asking a question?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/285557)

Comment: The question as yet lacks a [a specific programming problem](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic). Pragmatically there are issues with the code shown in the image. The use clause making declarations found in package numeric_std isn't made use of and is unneeded. r_array1 isn't an array type, it's a scalar (integer). You can't index it. If it were r_array_index(i + 1) would be out of range for i = 7 causing an error. Signal r_sqrValue1 isn't used.

Answer (score 1):

In VHDL, a `for loop` is a shorthand notation for creating parallel paths of logic.

In your example, the loop becomes a shift-by-1 index mapping assignment:

```
r_array(1) <= myArray1(0);
r_array(2) <= myArray1(1);
r_array(3) <= myArray1(2);
r_array(4) <= myArray1(3);
r_array(5) <= myArray1(4);
r_array(6) <= myArray1(5);
r_array(7) <= myArray1(6);
```

Since `r_array` is scalar type `integer` type and not a vector, this won't work as is.

Try using `r_array` as an index counter, then on each rising edge clock the next index of `myArray` will be assigned and our array index counter will increment by 1 (or wrap over back 0).

```
if rising_edge(i_CE1Hz) then
    
    if r_array <= 7 then
        r_array   <= r_array + 1;
    else
        r_array   <= 0;
    end if;

    o_element <= myArray(r_array); -- new output signal

end if;
```

Comment: myArray1 is an integer subtype not a composite array object. There are five errors in the code shown in the imag. The question *Could someone help with this, please ?* doesn't relate to a specific programming problem and is off-topic. See [answer], **Answer well-asked questions**. The purpose of the loop isn't clear it may not even be necessary.